# comparing two 2d arrays in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

I'm trying to compare two arrays both 2d, I need it only match when they're completely identical. The code I have is too lengthly, as the arrays will potentially be far longer. I tried playing with .each() and for loops but it get's very messy and won't compare every array.

```
var solution=[
[0,0,0],
[0,0,1],
[0,0,1]];

var value=[
[0,0,0],
[0,0,1],
[0,0,1]];

//compare arrays
    if (solution[0][0]==value[0][0] &&
        solution[0][1]==value[0][1] &&
        solution[0][2]==value[0][2] &&
        solution[1][0]==value[1][0] &&
        solution[1][1]==value[1][1] &&
        solution[1][2]==value[1][2] &&
        solution[2][0]==value[2][0] &&
        solution[2][1]==value[2][1] &&
        solution[2][2]==value[2][2]) { 

        $('h1').show();

    }
    else { $('h1').hide();}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

simple trick, by making them into strings :)

```
function equalArray(a, b) {
    return JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can compare arrays using

```
 $(solution).compare(value)
```