# How to find matching column/row elements in two 2d array | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to find matching column elements between two 2d arrays

**Means I only want to find matching string values in those given arrays**
my arrays are :

```
//chars : "stack"
var x = [["s",0],["t",2],["a",3],["c",1],["k",2]];

// chars: "exchange"
var x = [["e",0],["x",2],["c",3],["h",1],["a",2],["n",3],["g",2],["e",3]];
```

Here the character "a" is matching in columns, **want to store its index/value in a variable**

Help, how can I do it **in JavaScript (not in jQuery)**

Comment: So you want to find both indices here? What is the exact result you want to get?

Comment: yes i want doth indexes , i only want to know which string value is matching now the numeric values in these arrays, like here "a" is matching

Comment: But what happens if the same letter occurs several times?

Comment: I think two nested for loops can do it.

Comment: @SpiderPig  i also want to save those multiple values/indexes.

Comment: @Prusse please show me how

Comment: Is your question "how to find an intersection between two nested array"?

Comment: @Prusse i find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775658/comparing-two-2d-arrays-in-jquery ,,,,,,,,,,,,,, but i want to only compare and find column values so im stuck

Comment: @TaoP.R.      , i think so.. but for columns only

Comment: `c` is also present in both arrays. Doesn't that count?

Comment: The only part in common between your question and that is they both deal with 2d arrays... How to do it: (1) name the two arrays with distinct names; (2) create an object/array to hold the results; (3) iterate in the second array; (4) for each item iterate in the first to see if the is a matching value, if yes record the index and value of the found item in the result;

Comment: A better example would help. What is the exact result you want to get for a specific input. e.g. given the input `[["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 5], ["c", 8]]` and `[["c", 1], ["a", 2], ["d", 7], ["d", 9]]` one possible output could be `[["a", [0, 2], [1]], ["c", [3], [0]]]`

Comment: @Prusse sorry but im beginner to java-script , can you please give me the code

Comment: @SpiderPig , thats exactly want i want . can you write the code for it.

Comment: @Andy , please solve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By naive brute-force loops, you should be able to find matches between two blocks like this:

```
var x = [["s",0],["t",2],["a",3],["c",1],["k",2]];
var y = [["e",0],["x",2],["c",3],["h",1],["a",2],["n",3],["g",2],["e",3]];


function intersection(ax,bx){
    var matches = [];
    ax.forEach(function (a,i){
        bx.forEach(function (b,j){
            if (a[0]===b[0]){ // NOTE: make sure you use STRICT EQUAL
                matches.push([a[0],[i,j],[a[1],b[1]]]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When calling `intersection(x,y)` it should give you an array of the intersection which looks like this:

```
[['a',[2,4],[3,2]]]
```

The 2nd element is the indices of matching elements [2,4]
where the 3rd element is the values [3,2]

If multiple matches are found, you'll get all of matches like follows:

```
[['a',[2,4],[3,2]], [['b',[3,5],[3,2]]]] // Just example
```

Comment: thanx , but what if multiple item matches??

Comment: This matches multiple items and store all matches in the returning array

Comment: You can modify the snippet to formulate the output as desired. Let me know if you doubt in any part.

Comment: what is "ax.forEach(**function (a,i)**" doing.

Comment: Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
array.forEach( function(a, index){} ) iterates through the array and call the function you give as argument. For each item, `a` is an element with the index `i`.

Comment: The **MDN reference** link I've given above is very useful for you to quickly learn how to manipulate array in JS. I suggest you to spend some time on it and the resources are worth learning for the beginner to become more familiar with the language.

Comment: If this answers your question and you find it helpful. You can mark it as answer and vote up for it :)

Comment: oh sorry im new to stackoverflow, i forgot . i m doing it now.. thanx for the help you were very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getIndices(a, b) {
  function toObject(columns) {
    var o = {};
    columns.forEach(function(column, i) {
      var indices = o[column[0]] || [];
      indices.push(i);
      o[column[0]] = indices;
    });
    return o;
  }
  var oa = toObject(a),
      ob = toObject(b),
      result = [];
  Object.keys(oa).forEach(function(key) {
    if(ob[key]) result.push([key, oa[key], ob[key]]);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getIndices([["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 5], ["c", 8]], [["c", 1], ["a", 2], ["d", 7], ["d", 9]]));
```

Comment: thats too complicated for me

Answer (score 0):

```js
//chars : "stack"
var x = [["s",0],["t",2],["a",3],["c",1],["k",2]];

(function(){
// chars: "exchange"
var x = [["e",0],["x",2],["c",3],["h",1],["a",2],["n",3],["g",2],["e",3], ["a",7]];

  var result = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i){
    var x_key = x[i][0];
    for(var j = 0; j < window.x.length; ++j){
      if (x_key == window.x[j][0]){
        
        result[x_key] = result[x_key] || [];
        result[x_key].push({index: i, value: x[i][1]});
      }
    }
  }
  
  alert(JSON.stringify(result))
})();;
```

Comment: why are you using array inside function

Comment: You  gave them the same name... just changing scopes to be able to have that and have the two distinct objects...